# using jdbc.proprties in context.xml and persistence.xml

Tags: tomcat, jpa, jdbc, persistence

I have a jdbc.properties file and context.xml and persistence.xml

Is there a way to use the jdbc.properties in context and /or persistence.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Closest what you can get is specifying those variables as VM arguments. The `persistence.xml` has support for this in flavor of EL-like `${}` resolving.

E.g.

```
-Ddatasource=jdbc/mydatasource
```

with

```xml
<jta-data-source>${datasource}</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't have support for anything like that.